# Why is it that when i try to update something on apple store it doesn't let me

Tags: icloud, apple-id, mac-appstore

This has been happening a lot i'd try to update my VPN or any other app but apple store gives me an ID that isn't mine and I can't click on it to edit and type in the right one so I can't update any of my apps.

I am the only one using the account I don't share it with anyone and I haven't lent it to anyone
Here are screenshots of the problem

[image]

I try to update it then it asks me to put in login details but the apple ID there isn't mine

[image]

so if I put in my password it doesn't work

[image]

Because of that I haven't been able to use any app once it needs an update i have downloaded countless vpn's because once they need an update I am unable to do so and because of that the app stops working

I thought it was cause of icloud but I logged in and the issue persisted

Comment: Has the Mac been yours since new, or did it have a previous owner? If it had a previous owner, was the Mac **fully** erased & set up as new when you first got it? Do you use Family Sharing at all? Is the email address [which I anonymised in the photos] one you recognise as belonging to someone you know?

Comment: It is completely new and it is for school so I don't used family sharing and I have never seen that email

Comment: idk if the info is of any use, but bigpond is owned by Telstra - both Australian telecoms companies.

Answer (score 2):

This happens mostly when you get an app purchased from another person installed on your Mac. It could also be a result of a severely broken install.

- do you have a back up of your Mac? If so you’re set to do an erase install and before you reinstall anything, sign in to the App Store and test redownloading everything to ensure your store account is clean.

If not, you could do a smaller test by deleting the app rather than update it. Then redownload it to test.

In any case, this might need Apple support since only they can review your purchase history and see why the servers might have your account confused if you don’t think you mixed apps from the other accounts on your system.

This mixing of accounts often happens in schools and businesses where they don’t have an MDM to push updates and just used one account to get started. Be sure you check with your support team if this is the case before erasing, but do get a backup of your files in any case.